# Meaning of this word (Character identified: 緣)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

I just bought a couple of tea cups which I think are Japanese in style, but they could be Chinese. There's some writing on the cups that I was unable to translate with Google:

[image]

Does anyone know if the writing in this image is Chinese and if yes, what it means please?

Comment: 緣 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2864/  destiny; fate; predestined relationship

Comment: Thanks a lot Tang Ho! :)

Answer (score 1):

缘 is a kind of destiny for meeting someone or something.

[image]

Comment: How about translating the couplet on the scroll?

Comment: @WayneCheah, The Sky (or God) defines the 缘, however, people have to make efforts to achieve it. For example, Sky lets 2 people encounter, they have to do something for them being together.

Comment: Thanks for the translation.

Answer (score 0):

緣=缘
first one is traditional chinese, second one is simplified chinese.
it means fate to meet someone or something. Or luck or chance to meet someone or something.
especially, it is often used to describe love story.

Comment: Thanks Ning! :)

Answer (score 0):

This word is very Buddhist and is the core of universal concept of Buddhism.  Roughly, it means "random (as in timing) encounter/happening through lots of previous efforts".  From the birth of universe to falling in love with someone, all because of it.  But, also important is that it might also disappear randomly, obviously, through negative efforts.  In a way, "force" in Star Wars is roughly based on this concept therefor there is the "Dark Side of the Force".  In Chinese 缘起缘灭 covers all happening in this universe, based on the Buddhism philosophy.